# Allow users to download files without revealing link and without buffering

Tags: django, http, rackspace

I am hosting some video files in rackspace cloud files, and each user is allowed to download the files that are assigned to them.

Because of the file sizes it is not feasible to buffer the object in the webserver(webfaction)

I tried a redirect to the file, with Content-Disposition set to attachment, but to no avail.

What kind of options do I have, if any?

Ideally the file download would pop as coming from my domain after clicking a link that points to something like example.com/video/42/download/ so I can handle authentication ect. but im not sure how to structure my view for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best served by using an `HttpResponseRedirect` unless there is something I am misunderstanding...?

```
# urls.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
url(r'^applications/(?P<id>\d+)/image\.png$', 'core.views.serve_image', name='image'),
```

This will serve a view at `http://localhost/application/12345/image.png`.

```
# core/views.py

def serve_application_image(request, id):
    # redirect to temp_url
    application = Application.objects.get(id=id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(application.image.temp_url)
```

And this will redirect users that hit that URL to the Rackspace URL. It can work for embedding videos, images, etc, in html `<img>` tags and such. Browser clients *will* be able to see the redirected URL (at rackcdn.com).

---

I have configured my apps to serve a `temp_url` property that expires after 15 minutes. The temporary URL is created for the CDN at Rackspace.com and their documentation may be out of the scope for this question so I'll leave it off for now... but the code I use to sub-class `ImageField` to serve image attributes with the `.temp_url` code follows:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from time import time
class ImageFieldFile_With_Temp_Url(ImageFieldFile):
    @property
    def temp_url(self):

        container_name, file_name = (self.storage.container.name, self.name)

        key = settings.CUMULUS['CUSTOM__X_ACCOUNT_META_TEMP_URL_KEY']
        public_url = settings.CUMULUS['CUSTOM__X_STORAGE_URL']
        method = 'GET'
        expires = int(time() + settings.CUMULUS['CUSTOM__X_TEMP_URL_TIMEOUT'])

        url = '%s/%s/%s' % (public_url, container_name, file_name)
        base_url, object_path = url.split('/v1/')
        object_path = '/v1/' + object_path

        hmac_body = '%s\n%s\n%s' % (method, expires, object_path)
        sig = hmac.new(key, hmac_body, sha1).hexdigest()
        return '%s%s?temp_url_sig=%s&temp_url_expires=%s' % (base_url, object_path, sig, expires)

class ImageField_With_Temp_Url(models.ImageField):
    attr_class = ImageFieldFile_With_Temp_Url
models.ImageField = ImageField_With_Temp_Url
```

Note that I am using the [django-cumulus](https://github.com/django-cumulus/django-cumulus) project in this approach.

Importing this function anywhere at the top of your models.py will extend `ImageField` with a new `temp_url` property (since I assign it to `models.ImageField` ...).

Comment: I'm already using a HttpRedirectResponse, but that just redirects the user directly to the link at rackcdn which is kind of what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You may be able to use some combination of `urllib` and `FileWrapper` to stream it in 8kb chunks or so. http://blog.ekini.net/2010/10/15/file-streaming-in-django-sending-large-files-through-django/